# How to UNION tables and make results accessible in a Ruby view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, union

I'm quite new to RoR and creating a student project for a course I'm taking. I'm wanting to construct a type of query we didn't cover in the course and which I know I could do in a snap in .NET and SQL. I'm having a heck of a time though getting it implemented the Ruby way.

**What I'd like to do:** Display a list on a user's page of all "posts" by that user's friends.

"Posts" are found in both a `questions` table and in a `blurbs` table that users contribute to. I'd like to `UNION` these two into a single recordset to sort by updated_at DESC.

The table column names are not the same however, and this is my sticking point since other successful answers I've seen have hinged on column names being the same between the two.

In SQL I'd write something like (emphasis on *like*):

```
SELECT b.Blurb AS 'UserPost', b.updated_at, u.username as 'Author'
FROM Blurbs b
INNER JOIN Users u ON b.User_ID = u.ID
WHERE u.ID IN 
  (SELECT f.friend_id FROM Friendships f WHERE f.User_ID = [current user])
ORDER BY b.updated_at DESC

UNION

SELECT q.Question, q.updated_at, u.username
FROM Questions q
INNER JOIN Users u ON q.User_ID = u.ID
WHERE u.ID IN 
  (SELECT f.friend_id FROM Friendships f WHERE f.User_ID = [current user])
ORDER BY b.updated_at DESC
```

The User model's (applicable) relationships are:

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, through: :friendships
has_many :questions
has_many :blurbs
```

And the Question and Blurb models both have `belongs_to :user`

In the view I'd like to display the contents of the 'UserPost' column and the 'Author'. I'm sure this is possible, I'm just too new still to ActiveRecord and how statements are formed. Happy to have some input or review any relevant links that speak to this specifically!

**Final Solution**

Hopefully this will assist others in the future with Ruby `UNION` questions. Thanks to @Plamena's input the final implementation ended up as:

```
def friend_posts
  sql = "...the UNION statement seen above..."

  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(ActiveRecord::Base.send("sanitize_sql_array",[sql, self.id, self.id] ) )
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Active Record lacks union support. You can use SQL:

```
sql = <<-SQL
  # your sql query goes here
  SELECT b.created_at ...
  UNION(
    SELECT q.created_at
    ....
  )
SQL

posts = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql)
```

Then you can iterate the result:

```
posts.each do |post|
 # post is a hash
 p post['created_at']
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I spent hours on this yesterday with no luck. This works like a charm. I used your answer and looked up the `select_all` to see how to pass parameters, ending up with a complete solution where the last line looks like: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(ActiveRecord::Base.send("sanitize_sql_array",[sql, self.id, self.id]))`

Answer (score 0):

Your best way to do this is to just use the power of Rails

If you want all of something belonging to a user's friend:

```
current_user.friends.find(id_of_friend).first.questions
```

This would get all of the questions from a certain friend.

Now, it seems that you have writings in multiple places (this is hard to visualise without your providing a model of how writings is connected to everywhere else). Can you provide this?

Comment: I've updated the original post with some clarification in the 2nd paragraph. I thought I accurately described both the tables and the models, let me know what would be of more help in clarifying.

Comment: Also, I'm looking for all questions written by all of the current user's friends (not just one friend). AND all blurbs written by all of the current user's friends. And somehow merging these two into a single list so that it can be sorted in DESC order by date.

Answer (score 0):

```
@blurbs = Blurb.includes(:user)

@blurbs.each do |blurb|
  p blurb.blurb, blurb.user.username
end
```

Comment: This is great and is what I've also seen elsewhere. I have the added complexity of wanting both blurbs *and* questions (two different tables with differing column names). And to mesh those two sets together so they're sorted DESC by updated_at.